# Remove Default Background Color and Make Title in Plot Zone

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this `ggplot2` plot which I want to modify to fit the following conditions:

1. Remove default background that is hash colour to be plain.
2. Make `(a)` to be the plot title located within the plot area that is not close to the line (automatically).
3. Make `$\phi = .8$` to be automatically at the head of the line (still within the plot area).
4. And `sd = 1` to be automatically at the tail of the line.

**EDIT**

5. The four(4) Border lines to be present.
6. Gridlines to be grey colour.

.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(799837)
ts <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)

gplot <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = ts, x = seq_along(ts))) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,2)) +
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Series') + ggtitle(expression("(a)\nsd = 1\n"~phi~"=.8")) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0, vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0.0), axis.title = element_text(size = 10), axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 10), axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 14), plot.title = element_text(size = 14, margin = margin(t = 25, b = -20, l = 0, r = 0))) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

gplot
```

[image: ggplot here]

Comment: grey gridlines can be added with `theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="grey"))` (and `panel.grid.minor` for extra gridlines). Panel border can be added with `theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how of this might look semi automatic. The specifics depend on how different your actual time series data is, but this might help as inspiration. Exact positions and text styling can of course be tweaked to your liking.

```
set.seed(799837)
ts <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)    

gplot <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = ts, x = seq_along(ts))) + 
      geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + 
      geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + 
      annotate("text", x = mean(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.1, label = "(a)")+
      annotate("text", x = min(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.1, label = 'paste(~phi~"=.8")', parse = TRUE )+ 
      annotate("text", x= max(seq_along(ts)), y = ts[[max(seq_along(ts))]] * 1.1, label = "sd=1") +
      xlab('Time') + 
      ylab('Series') + 
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0, vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0.0), 
            axis.title = element_text(size = 10), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 10), 
            axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 14), 
            plot.title = element_text(size = 14, margin = margin(t = 25, b = -20, l = 0, r = 0)),
            panel.background = element_blank()) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,2)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))
```

[image]

Comment: `Error in max(ts) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument `

Comment: Did you maybe not create the timeseries data before running my code? You need to initialize the same way you did before you started plotting: `set.seed(799837)
ts <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: `Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'`

Comment: Changed the labeling in annotate to not use `expression()`. Now the warning should be gone.

Comment: Please note my edit.