# GGPLOT2: Adjust Font Size of Plot Title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have This `ggplot2` I made up to satisfy these conditions:

1. Remove default background that is hash colour to be plain.
2. Make (a) to be the plot title located within the plot area that is not close to the line (automatically).
3. Make $\phi = .8$ to be automatically at the head of the line (still within the plot area).
4. And sd = 1 to be automatically at the tail of the line.
5. The four(4) Borderlines to be present.
6. Gridlines to be a grey colour.

.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(799837)
ts <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)

gplot <- ggplot(NULL, aes(y = ts, x = seq_along(ts))) + 
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + 
  geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + 
  annotate("text", x = mean(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.1, label = "(a)")+
  annotate("text", x = min(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.1, label = 'paste(~phi~"=.8")', parse = TRUE )+ 
  annotate("text", x= max(seq_along(ts)), y = ts[[max(seq_along(ts))]] * 1.1, label = "sd=1") +
  xlab('Time') + 
  ylab('Series') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 40, angle = 0, vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0.0), #y-axis label size
        axis.title = element_text(size = 40), #x-axis label size
        axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 40), # x-axis title
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 40), # y-axis title
        plot.title = element_text(size = 40, margin = margin(t = 25, b = -20, l = 0, r = 0)),
        panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))
gplot
```

[image: ggplot2 output]

I want the font of the plot title to increase. As you can see that despite setting the font of the plot title to 40 the font title refuse to increase. This question is a follow-up question from [Remove Default Background Color and Make Title in Plot Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809241/remove-default-background-color-and-make-title-in-plot-zone?noredirect=1#comment123400983_69809241)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel

If `(a)` is the 'title' it's not *really* the title, it's an annotation.

So to change it's size do it when you add the annotation.

```
annotate("text", x = mean(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.5, label = "(a)", size = 40)
```

[image]

You might also want to resize the other annotations.

```
  annotate("text", x = mean(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.5, label = "(a)", size = 40) +
  annotate("text", x = min(seq_along(ts)), y = max(ts) * 1.5, label = 'paste(~phi~"=.8")', parse = TRUE, size = 10)+ 
  annotate("text", x= max(seq_along(ts)), y = ts[[max(seq_along(ts))]] * 1.5, label = "sd=1", size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can place the `annotations automatically position the plot area without setting it manually and it will not interfere with the plot?

Comment: Not sure about positioning the annotations automatically, aren't you sort of doing that already?. As for not interfering you might want to look at this package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html